# My images resize with window, but not when browser zooms

Tags: zooming

My images resize with window resize, but not when browser zooms.

Image is a transparent gif.

```
.imageClass {
    width:  75%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Appreciate any help in advance ...

Comment: It also depends on your image wrapper element's settings. Could you provide a simple html code to produce your issue?

Comment: Point of confusion = when I pinch-zoom + or - on my iPhone, the above works just great.  But, when I zoom + or - on my desktop Browser, the above css "jerks" around, e.g., sometimes when I zoom up, the image will first get smaller before it gets larger.  ???  I love the iPhone response because it zooms correctly.  Not so much on my desktop (iMac).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've neglected to address your image wrapper question. I do not have an image wrapper surrounding the <img>, just a class="imageClass". Oh my goodness, I just tested zooming on this stackoverflow website and it zooms correctly.  Need to look into it!!